# Start and Stop pattern in golang

Tags: go, design-patterns

There are several components with a common functionality of starting and stopping a service (with the ability to restart it). It is necessary to extract this common functionality into a separate component. Support for concurrency. Description of interface requirements.

```golang
start_stop_pattern

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

var (
    ErrAlreadyRunning = errors.New("already running")
    ErrNothingStopped = errors.New("nothing stopped")
)

// New
// f is a user function with a context through which
// the function can determine if Stop was called.
// The user function is not required to use ctx.
func New(f func(ctx context.Context) error) *Service {
    return &Service{}
}

type Service struct{}

// Start
// Starts the passed f user function.
// If Start is already running, returns ErrAlreadyRunning.
func (s *Service) Start() error {}

// Stop
// Stops the execution of the f user function if Start is running and waits for it to complete.
// If Start is not running, returns error ErrNothingStopped.
// After calling Stop, Start can be run again.
func (s *Service) Stop() error {}
```

Tests

```golang
package start_stop_pattern

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestService(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("race test", func(t *testing.T) {
        srv := New(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            for {
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    return nil
                case <-time.NewTicker(1 * time.Millisecond).C:
                }
            }
        }, time.Millisecond*10)

        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                _ = srv.Start()
                wg.Done()
            }()

            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                srv.Stop()
                wg.Done()
            }()
        }

        wg.Wait()
    })
    t.Run("running with done", func(t *testing.T) {
        srv := New(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            for {
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    log.Println("service stop")
                    return nil
                case <-time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond).C:
                    log.Println("some do")
                }
            }
        }, time.Millisecond*100)

        done := make(chan struct{})
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            require.ErrorIs(t, srv.Start(), ErrAlreadyRunning)
            require.NoError(t, srv.Stop())

            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            require.ErrorIs(t, srv.Stop(), ErrNothingToStop)

            close(done)
        }()

        require.NoError(t, srv.Start())

        <-done
    })
    t.Run("running without done", func(t *testing.T) {
        srv := New(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            return nil
        }, time.Millisecond*10)

        done := make(chan struct{})
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            require.ErrorIs(t, srv.Start(), ErrAlreadyRunning)
            require.ErrorIs(t, srv.Stop(), ErrNothingStopped)

            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            require.ErrorIs(t, srv.Stop(), ErrNothingStopped)

            close(done)
        }()

        require.NoError(t, srv.Start())

        <-done

        srv.Stop()
    })
}
```

It is not possible to implement functionality that satisfies all requirements.